# Why is part of the text being cut off by the background of the sticky header?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I'm currently trying to create a sticky rotated header for the html table. Currently part of the text is being cut off by the background of the sticky header, and I've tried playing around with the css and change the z-index of other elements, but nothing seems to be helping. I'm not sure if I'm implementing this in an incorrect fashion, or if there was a better way to do. Here's my html code -

```css
.rotated-header{
  width:30px;
  height:80px;
  position:relative;
  transform:
      translate(30px, 50px)
      rotate(315deg);
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.header {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tableFixHead {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header">Asset</th>
      <th class="header">
        <div class="rotated-header">
          <span>Rotated row 1</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header">
        <div class="rotated-header">
          <span>Rotated row 2</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make just the table row sticky instead of making each of the heading *cells* sticky as [Konrad Linkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5089567/konrad-linkowski) said in a comment.

```css
.tableFixHead thead tr {
    position: sticky;
}
```

```css
.rotated-header {
  width: 30px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(30px, 50px) rotate(315deg);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tableFixHead {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.tableFixHead thead tr {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="header">Asset</th>
        <th class="header">
          <div class="rotated-header">
            <span>Rotated row 1</span>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th class="header">
          <div class="rotated-header">
            <span>Rotated row 2</span>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
        <td>some</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to remove `width` and add `top`. or simply just make `.tableFixHead thead th` background transparent like so

```css
.rotated-header{
  height:80px;
  width: 30px;
  position:relative;
  transform:
      translate(30px, 50px)
      rotate(315deg);
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.header {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.tableFixHead {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 150px;
}

.tableFixHead thead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background:transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header">Asset</th>
      <th class="header">
        <div class="rotated-header">
          <span >Rotated row 1</span>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th class="header">
        <div class="rotated-header">
          <span >Rotated row 2</span>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
      <td>some</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```